# Saving array of objects with jQuery AJAX and PHP?

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, fullcalendar

Hi I'm using fullcalendar, jQuery and CakePHP. When using the clientEvents function I get all of the calendar events in an array of objects. I then pass that array to an action via jQuery's $.ajax of type post. But when I inspect the post data I get something like:

```
Array
(
    [undefined] => undefined
)
```

What seems to be the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This probably means you're not building the array in Javascript correctly. Something like

```
values = myValues();  // getting values
var data = { };
data[values.variableThatDoesNotExist] = values.anotherVariableThatDoesNotExist;
```

The two non-existing variables are of type `undefined`, which gets cast to the string "undefined", and that's what the key and value in the object will be called.

Try debugging your Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post("/url/to/post/to",
       { post_param1: value1, post_param2: value2 }
       function(response) {
       }
});
```

Should work great...